# Getting diagonal elements over several dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'd like to transform a tensor T of size (n x n x m x m) into a tensor U of size (n x m x m)  while only retreiving the diagonal elements of T over the (NxN) chunks (i.e. Uikl=Tiikl). torch.diag() only works with 2-D tensors and I really fail to see how to do this without looping on the indexes of the elements (which I'd like to avoid given that I think that it is inefficient computationnally). In clear, I'd like to vectorize the following code:

```
U = torch.zeros(n, m, m)
for i in range(n):
    for k in range(m):
        for l in range(m):
            U[i][k][l] = T[i][i][k][l]
```

I'm totally new to pytorch and I tried many combination of functions but none of them gives me a satisfying result. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the indexes using `np.meshgrid`

```
i, k, l = np.meshgrid(range(n), range(m), range(m))
U[i, k, l] = T[i, i, k, l]
```

for completeness I did:

```
n = 3
m = 5

T = torch.arange(n * n * m * m).view(n, n, m, m)
U = torch.zeros(n, m, m)
U_ = torch.zeros(n, m, m)

i, k, l = np.meshgrid(range(n), range(m), range(m))

U_[i, k, l] = T[i, i, k, l]

for i in range(n):
    for k in range(m):
        for l in range(m):
            U[i][k][l] = T[i][i][k][l]

U = U.view(-1)
U_ = U_.view(-1)

print ((U == U_).all())
```

The output is `True` so I assume it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When applied to 2d matrices, `torch.diag()` is an alias for `torch.diagonal()`.

`diagonal` itself allows you to specify which two dimensions of an arbitrary rank tensor the diagonal is taken from, by default these are 0 and 1:

```py
U = T.diagonal()
```